# Determining a bound on the rationals in abstract algerbra.

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

For the following subset of the rational numbers, determine if the set 
1) has a maximum
2) an upper bound
3) a least upper bound.

The set is: $\{ \frac {a}{b} \space | \space  a,b \in \mathbb {Z^{+}}, \space a^2 -ab - b^2 <0 \}$.

In this definition, $0$ isn't in $ \mathbb {Z^{+}} $. It also has a note: "you may assume there is no rational number $r$ with $ r^2 =5$"

I don't understand the note, mostly because I don't see how this set is bounded in any way.

Is this set somehow bounded? If it is what is its least upper bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Observe
\begin{align}
a^2-ab-b^2= \left(a-\frac{b}{2}\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}b^2 = b^2\left\{ \left( \frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{5}{4}\right\}<0
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\left( \frac{a}{b}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2<\frac{5}{4}.
\end{align}